# Hive showing non-existing partitions

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

I have a table in hive whose DDL looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id string) PARTITIONED BY (data_updated string,batch_id string,country string,state string);

data_updated=NO/batch_id=102/country='1'/state='A';
data_updated=NO/batch_id=103/country='2'/state='B';
data_updated=NO/batch_id=104/country='3'/state='C';
```

I want to move the data from data_updated=NO to data_updated=YES. And I do that via HDFS commands.

```
data_updated=YES/batch_id=102/country='1'/state='A'
data_updated=YES/batch_id=103/country='2'/state='B'
data_updated=YES/batch_id=104/country='3'/state='C'
```

One option is to write the multiple rename partition DDLs. But, alter partition DDLs require all partitions to be specified upto Nth level. N-level is dynamic and cannot be statically determined.

I am getting the batch_ids with the help of unix script and moving the directory manually using move command in HDFS.

```
Inside a loop:
hadoop fs -mv /table/directory/data_processed=NO/batch_id=$i /table/directory/data_processed=YES/
```

The problem with moving with HDFS commands is after repairing the table in hive, the non existing partitions still exists in hive metadata. How to remove non-existing partitions from hive metadata. Any suggestions?

Output of show partition in hive.

```
show partitions test;

data_updated=NO/batch_id=102/country='1'/state='A'; # NON-EXISTING
data_updated=NO/batch_id=103/country='2'/state='B'; # NON-EXISTING
data_updated=NO/batch_id=104/country='3'/state='C'; # NON-EXISTING
data_updated=YES/batch_id=102/country='1'/state='A'
data_updated=YES/batch_id=103/country='2'/state='B'
data_updated=YES/batch_id=104/country='3'/state='C'
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there is no way from Hive to remove partitions based on missing hdfs directories. The easiest way that I see is drop your partitions base on conditions like this

```
alter table test drop if exists partition (data_updated='NO');
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108251/how-to-update-partition-metadata-in-hive-when-partition-data-is-manualy-delete?rq=1), `msck repair table` will not delete any metadata from the metastore for partitions manually deleted. For that you will have to run `alter table drop partition (...)` to update the metadata.

Since your partitions are dynamically generated, I would suggest you write a script to run the `alter table` commands, rather than running them manually. For example:

```
for path in $(hive -e "show partitions test" | grep "data_updated=NO")
do
  part=$(echo $path | tr "/" " ")
  echo "alter table test drop partitions($(echo $part | tr " " ","));"
done > drop_partitions.hql
```